# custom_post_type with umlaut in name

Tags: custom-post-types

hi and thanks for stopping by.
i created a custom_post_type like this:

```
function custom_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'veroeffentlichungen',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Veröffentlichungen' ),
                'menu_name' => 'Veröffentlichung'
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'veroeffentlichungen')
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_types' );
```

this works fine.
now i need the navigation to show the class, when im on a single page in that post type `.current-menu-item`

i do that with following function (print_r's included..):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_type_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function current_type_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    print_r($item);
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    print_r($post_type);
    if ($item->post_name != '' && $item->post_name == $post_type) {
        array_push($classes, 'current-menu-item');
    };
    return $classes;
}
```

but the results from the `print_r()`'s are different:

```
$post_type       = veroeffentlichungen
$item->post_name = veroffentlichungen
```

the ö should turn into oe, NOT into o, but i dont know, where to edit the `$item->post_name`, i guess that should be done inside the labels array, but i couldnt find a solution in the codex.

the output of `print_r($item)` is

```
WP_Post Object
(
    ...
    [post_title] => Veröffentlichungen
    ...
    [post_name] => veroffentlichungen
    ...
    [title] => Veröffentlichungen
    [url] => /veroeffentlichungen/
    ...
)
```

Comment: i just added a page in wp with an umlaut in the title and the slug generated by wp converts the ä into a, instead of ae. so i guess its some *magic wp engine*, that is doing this wrong. but that is above my imagination (and skills).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i now changed the navigation function to check for the url, since this one was right in all cases (i do have some other custom_post_types, that worked fine and still do).
i just needed to strip the slashes from the url:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_type_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function current_type_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($item->post_name != '' && str_replace("/", "", $item->url) == $post_type) {
        array_push($classes, 'current-menu-item');
    };
    return $classes;
}
```